# jenkins job build not in slave node

Tags: jenkins

build job( build docker image ,code from github)  in slave machine by configuration,but it do not build success...if change job in master ,it build success
slave build message :

```
Started by user admin
Building remotely on jenkins-slave (slave) in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/71bnh8co385ctlmoxgbumdnpnet3ywq
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:xxxxxxx/wcount.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/workspace/71bnh8co385ctlmoxgbumdnpnet3ywq # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:xxxxxxx/wcount.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 71bnh6gke9kmabye9qu2qsazzpofjsa
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress     git@github.com:xxxxxxx/wcount.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:xxxxxxx/wcount.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:xxxxxxx/wcount.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:xxxxxxx/wcount.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 71bnh6gke9kmabye9qu2qsazzpofjsa
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress     git@github.com:xxxxxxx/wcount.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 5730301886fa5c02522705de817c5ddac0f0dbce (origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 5730301886fa5c02522705de817c5ddac0f0dbce
 > git rev-list 5730301886fa5c02522705de817c5ddac0f0dbce # timeout=10
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: configured dockerFolder     '/home/jenkins/workspace/71bnh8co385ctlmoxgbumdnpnet3ywq' does not exist.
        at     org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.cmd.CreateImageCommand.execute(CreateImageCommand.java:93)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:75)
```

master workspace is /home/jenkins_home/workspace
slave  workspace is /home/jenkins/workspace
i can find /home/jenkins/workspace/71bnh8co385ctlmoxgbumdnpnet3ywq directory in slave node。
i guess this build in master node,but i see the task in slave queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jenkins docker-build-step plugin don't support task run on slave node,so you can change some code to support it 。
   add a jar to slave which can  create image and push image。then master invoke   this jar in slave

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the case here, but it seems that Jenkins sets a path to Dockerfile in `Docker build/create` task at Build stage as `$WORKSPACE/docker` so you either have to ensure you have that folder (containing Dockerfile and other needed files) in your workspace/git repo or just remove `docker` from path ENV above (which is a better solution, imho) and Jenkins will read Dockerfile from main workspace/git directory. Hope that helps.